# Python App Servers (Bjoern vs Gunicorn)

Tags: python, performance, webserver, gunicorn, bjoern

I am benchmarking python WSGI app servers.

I am running bjoern as follows:

```
bjoern.run(wsgi_app, host, port)
```

And Gunicorn as such:

```
gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 gun_server:wsgi_app --log-level=DEBUG --timeout 90
```

However, I am observing that Bjoern is handling half as many requests as Gunicorn. The node I am benchmarking on has 2 vCPUs.

According to many articles published so far (for e.g)
https://dzone.com/articles/a-performance-analysis-of-python-wsgi-servers-part Bjoern is supposed to be way better at handling many requests per second as compared to Gunicorn.

Followed this to enable Bjoren to run on multiple cores https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern/blob/master/tests/fork.py

However Bjoern still handles **just a bit more** than half the request handled by Gunicorn

Bjoren seems to be using multiple cores:

```
vin@TEST:~/api/src$ ps -U $USER -o pid,psr,comm | grep python
27880   1 python
27921   1 python
27922   1 python
vin@TEST:~/api/src$ ps -U $USER -o pid,psr,comm | grep python
27880   1 python
27921   1 python
27922   0 python
vin@TEST:~/api/src$ ps -U $USER -o pid,psr,comm | grep python
27880   1 python
27921   1 python
27922   1 python
vin@TEST:~/api/src$ ps -U $USER -o pid,psr,comm | grep python
27880   1 python
27921   1 python
27922   1 python
vin@TEST:~/api/src$ ps -U $USER -o pid,psr,comm | grep python
27880   1 python
27921   0 python
27922   0 python
```

Any ideas how to debug this?

**[UPDATE]**
I am on 3.2.0-115-virtual which does not support SO_REUSEPORT. Would this affect the request/sec substantially ?

Answer (score 2):

Bjoern is using one core, gunicorn is using two cores.
Therefore it makes sense, that gunicorn is handling (~2 times) more requests.

Comment: Yes, thanks, noticed that. I have updated the code using os.fork(). Benchmark is running at the moment.

Comment: Followed this: https://github.com/jonashaag/bjoern/blob/master/tests/fork.py
However, Bjoern is still handling half as much requests as Gunicorn. How should I debug this ? There are two processes

python(27880) ─┬─python(27921)
                           └─python(27922)

Comment: another thing I noticed was I am on Linux 3.2 where SO_REUSEPORT is not supported. Would this affect the requests/sec substantially ?